# Store Big Price value in database along with Decimal Point in SQLite Database

Tags: android, database, sqlite, numbers, decimal

May be my question is silly, But I didn't find any Solution for this. 
Actually, I want to Store Big Price Amount i.e.

> 9999999999.99

in Sqlite Database and want to retrive it back. I tried with TEXT, DOUBLE, REAL, LONG Datatypes.

Unfortunately when i do this, it returns me back unwanted value i.e. 9.999999999.. . Please suggest me if you have solution for this, or guide me.

Comment: You can use `REAL`

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya Tried it, But its also not helpful to me.

Comment: Same issue for `TEXT` ?

Comment: yes. :( Same issue.

Comment: Kindly show code.

Comment: Just Insert in DB using ContentValues

Comment: try with `BigDecimal`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162954/discussion-between-bhoomika-patel-and-intellij-amiya).

Comment: convert your Big Price Amount into string and store it as VARCHAR in db

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The defined column type affinity `TEXT`, `REAL`, `NUMERIC`, `VARCHAR`, `RUMPLESTILTSKIN` (*yes it works*), has little impact; the exception being if the type is either `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` or `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT` in which case the column is an alias of the SQLITE column **rowid** and cannot be used. [ROWIDs and the INTEGER PRIMARY KEY](https://sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid)

Basically any column, except a rowid, can store any type of value as per

> Any column in an SQLite version 3 database, except an INTEGER PRIMARY
>   KEY column, may be used to store a value of any storage class.
>   [Datatypes In SQLite Version 3](https://sqlite.org/datatype3.html)

The link also explains how column types are converted to one of the 5 column types :-

- TEXT,
- INTEGER,
- REAL,
- BLOB or
- NUMERIC.

RuMpleStilskin (case independent) will be converted to NUMERIC, as per :-

- (a) it doesn't contain **INT** (if so INTEGER affinity)
- (b) it doesn't conatain **TEXT**, **CHAR** or **CLOB** (if so TEXT affinity unless previously handled)
- (c) it doesn't contain **BLOB** (if so BLOB affinity unless previously handled)
- (d) it doesn't contain **REAL**, **FLOA**, or **DOUB** (if so REAL affinity unless previously handled)
- (e) if none of the above **NUMERIC** <<<< Rumplestilskin gets here.

What is of primary importance is how you retrieve the data, although the column's affinity can affect how the data is stored (the storage class) as per :-

> A column with TEXT affinity stores all data using storage classes
>   NULL, TEXT or BLOB. If numerical data is inserted into a column with
>   TEXT affinity it is converted into text form before being stored.
>
> A column with NUMERIC affinity may contain values using all five
>   storage classes. When text data is inserted into a NUMERIC column, the
>   storage class of the text is converted to INTEGER or REAL (in order of
>   preference) if such conversion is lossless and reversible. For
>   conversions between TEXT and REAL storage classes, SQLite considers
>   the conversion to be lossless and reversible if the first 15
>   significant decimal digits of the number are preserved. If the
>   lossless conversion of TEXT to INTEGER or REAL is not possible then
>   the value is stored using the TEXT storage class. No attempt is made
>   to convert NULL or BLOB values.
>
> A string might look like a floating-point literal with a decimal point
>   and/or exponent notation but as long as the value can be expressed as
>   an integer, the NUMERIC affinity will convert it into an integer.
>   Hence, the string '3.0e+5' is stored in a column with NUMERIC affinity
>   as the integer 300000, not as the floating point value 300000.0.
>
> A column that uses INTEGER affinity behaves the same as a column with
>   NUMERIC affinity. The difference between INTEGER and NUMERIC affinity
>   is only evident in a CAST expression.
>
> A column with REAL affinity behaves like a column with NUMERIC
>   affinity except that it forces integer values into floating point
>   representation. (As an internal optimization, small floating point
>   values with no fractional component and stored in columns with REAL
>   affinity are written to disk as integers in order to take up less
>   space and are automatically converted back into floating point as the
>   value is read out. This optimization is completely invisible at the
>   SQL level and can only be detected by examining the raw bits of the
>   database file.)
>
> A column with affinity BLOB does not prefer one storage class over
>   another and no attempt is made to coerce data from one storage class
>   into another.
>   [Datatypes In SQLite Version 3](https://sqlite.org/datatype3.html)

For floating point or double you should retrieve the data using the `Cursor` methods `getFloat` or `getDouble` and then format the result, if converting it to a string, accordingly. 
***Note! this assumes that the flaws/loss of precision with double or float are not relevant.*** 
If you store the value as a string and the column affinity is TEXT or BLOB then the result is loss-less and is perhaps the best way to store large (see results to determine what is large) numbers.

---

Consider a table with 5 columns defined with column types/affinities **REAL**, **TEXT**, **INTEGER**, **NUMERIC** and **BLOB**

as per :-

```
CREATE TABLE prices (
    _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
    PRICE1 REAL, 
    PRICE2 TEXT,
    PRICE3 INTEGER, 
    PRICE4 NUMERIC, 
    PRICE5 BLOB
)
```

- The ID column isn't of significance.

Now consider these 3 basic methods to 
- a) insert a double value into all 5 PRICE? columns
- b) insert a string value into all 5 PRICE? columns
- c) get all rows as a cursor
:-

```
public void insertRowFromDouble(double price) {
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(PRICES_PRICE1_COL,price);
    cv.put(PRICES_PRICE2_COL,price);
    cv.put(PRICES_PRICE3_COL,price);
    cv.put(PRICES_PRICE4_COl,price);
    cv.put(PRICES_PRICE5_COL,price);
    mDB.insert(TBNAME,null,cv);
}

public void insertRowFromString(String price) {
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(PRICES_PRICE1_COL,price);
    cv.put(PRICES_PRICE2_COL,price);
    cv.put(PRICES_PRICE3_COL,price);
    cv.put(PRICES_PRICE4_COl,price);
    cv.put(PRICES_PRICE5_COL,price);
    mDB.insert(TBNAME,null,cv);
}

public Cursor getAllRows() {
    return mDB.query(TBNAME,null,null,null,null,null,null);
}
```

and then consider the following code, which :-

- a) Creates a DecimalFormat
- b) Instantiates a Databasehelper
- c) Deletes all existing rows (for rerun-ability)
- d) Inserts 5 rows using the insertRowfromDouble method with varying values, each row having all 5 columns populated with the same value even though they each have a different column type.
- e) does the same as d) but using the insertRowFromString method and within different but close values.
- f) obtains a cursor with all 10 rows.
- g) loops through the cursor output the resultant data using the `getDouble` method formatted according to the `DecimalFormat` and then the `getString` method.

:-

```
    final DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#0.000000");
    mDBPricesHlpr = new PriceDBHelper(this);
    mDBPricesHlpr.getWritableDatabase().delete(PriceDBHelper.TBNAME,null,null);
    mDBPricesHlpr.insertRowFromDouble(999999999999999999999999999999999999999.99);
    mDBPricesHlpr.insertRowFromDouble(12345678901.123456);
    mDBPricesHlpr.insertRowFromDouble(9999999999.99);
    mDBPricesHlpr.insertRowFromDouble(0.01);
    mDBPricesHlpr.insertRowFromDouble(45678.45);
    mDBPricesHlpr.insertRowFromString("999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999.99");
    mDBPricesHlpr.insertRowFromString("12345678901.123456");
    mDBPricesHlpr.insertRowFromString("8888888888.88");
    mDBPricesHlpr.insertRowFromString("0.02");
    mDBPricesHlpr.insertRowFromString("56789.56");
    Cursor csr = mDBPricesHlpr.getAllRows();
    while (csr.moveToNext()) {
        Log.d("PRICEINFO_GETDBL"," Processing Row " + csr.getPosition() +
                "\n\tPRICE1=" + df.format(csr.getDouble(csr.getColumnIndex(PriceDBHelper.PRICES_PRICE1_COL))) +
                        "\n\tPRICE2=" + df.format(csr.getDouble(csr.getColumnIndex(PriceDBHelper.PRICES_PRICE2_COL))) +
                        "\n\tPRICE3=" + df.format(csr.getDouble(csr.getColumnIndex(PriceDBHelper.PRICES_PRICE3_COL))) +
                        "\n\tPRICE4=" + df.format(csr.getDouble(csr.getColumnIndex(PriceDBHelper.PRICES_PRICE4_COl))) +
                        "\n\tPRICE5=" + df.format(csr.getDouble(csr.getColumnIndex(PriceDBHelper.PRICES_PRICE5_COL)))
        );
        Log.d("PRICEINFO_GETSTR", " Processing Row " + csr.getPosition() +
                "\n\tPRICE1=" + csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(PriceDBHelper.PRICES_PRICE1_COL)) +
                        "\n\tPRICE2=" + csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(PriceDBHelper.PRICES_PRICE2_COL)) +
                        "\n\tPRICE3=" + csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(PriceDBHelper.PRICES_PRICE3_COL)) +
                        "\n\tPRICE4=" + csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(PriceDBHelper.PRICES_PRICE4_COl)) +
                        "\n\tPRICE5=" + csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(PriceDBHelper.PRICES_PRICE5_COL))
        );
    }
```

The resultant output is :-

```
01-11 10:39:30.626 3680-3680/? D/PRICEINFO_GETDBL:  Processing Row 0
                                                    PRICE1=1000000000000000000000000000000000000000.000000
                                                    PRICE2=1000000000000000000000000000000000000000.000000
                                                    PRICE3=1000000000000000000000000000000000000000.000000
                                                    PRICE4=1000000000000000000000000000000000000000.000000
                                                    PRICE5=1000000000000000000000000000000000000000.000000
01-11 10:39:30.626 3680-3680/? D/PRICEINFO_GETSTR:  Processing Row 0
                                                    PRICE1=1e+39
                                                    PRICE2=1.0e+39
                                                    PRICE3=1e+39
                                                    PRICE4=1e+39
                                                    PRICE5=1e+39
01-11 10:39:30.626 3680-3680/? D/PRICEINFO_GETDBL:  Processing Row 1
                                                    PRICE1=12345678901.123500
                                                    PRICE2=12345678901.123500
                                                    PRICE3=12345678901.123500
                                                    PRICE4=12345678901.123500
                                                    PRICE5=12345678901.123500
01-11 10:39:30.626 3680-3680/? D/PRICEINFO_GETSTR:  Processing Row 1
                                                    PRICE1=1.23457e+10
                                                    PRICE2=12345678901.1235
                                                    PRICE3=1.23457e+10
                                                    PRICE4=1.23457e+10
                                                    PRICE5=1.23457e+10
01-11 10:39:30.626 3680-3680/? D/PRICEINFO_GETDBL:  Processing Row 2
                                                    PRICE1=9999999999.990000
                                                    PRICE2=9999999999.990000
                                                    PRICE3=9999999999.990000
                                                    PRICE4=9999999999.990000
                                                    PRICE5=9999999999.990000
01-11 10:39:30.626 3680-3680/? D/PRICEINFO_GETSTR:  Processing Row 2
                                                    PRICE1=1e+10
                                                    PRICE2=9999999999.99
                                                    PRICE3=1e+10
                                                    PRICE4=1e+10
                                                    PRICE5=1e+10
01-11 10:39:30.626 3680-3680/? D/PRICEINFO_GETDBL:  Processing Row 3
                                                    PRICE1=0.010000
                                                    PRICE2=0.010000
                                                    PRICE3=0.010000
                                                    PRICE4=0.010000
                                                    PRICE5=0.010000
01-11 10:39:30.630 3680-3680/? D/PRICEINFO_GETSTR:  Processing Row 3
                                                    PRICE1=0.01
                                                    PRICE2=0.01
                                                    PRICE3=0.01
                                                    PRICE4=0.01
                                                    PRICE5=0.01
01-11 10:39:30.630 3680-3680/? D/PRICEINFO_GETDBL:  Processing Row 4
                                                    PRICE1=45678.450000
                                                    PRICE2=45678.450000
                                                    PRICE3=45678.450000
                                                    PRICE4=45678.450000
                                                    PRICE5=45678.450000
01-11 10:39:30.630 3680-3680/? D/PRICEINFO_GETSTR:  Processing Row 4
                                                    PRICE1=45678.4
                                                    PRICE2=45678.45
                                                    PRICE3=45678.4
                                                    PRICE4=45678.4
                                                    PRICE5=45678.4
01-11 10:39:30.630 3680-3680/? D/PRICEINFO_GETDBL:  Processing Row 5
                                                    PRICE1=1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.000000
                                                    PRICE2=1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.000000
                                                    PRICE3=1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.000000
                                                    PRICE4=1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.000000
                                                    PRICE5=1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.000000
01-11 10:39:30.630 3680-3680/? D/PRICEINFO_GETSTR:  Processing Row 5
                                                    PRICE1=1e+75
                                                    PRICE2=999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999.99
                                                    PRICE3=1e+75
                                                    PRICE4=1e+75
                                                    PRICE5=999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999.99
01-11 10:39:30.630 3680-3680/? D/PRICEINFO_GETDBL:  Processing Row 6
                                                    PRICE1=12345678901.123500
                                                    PRICE2=12345678901.123500
                                                    PRICE3=12345678901.123500
                                                    PRICE4=12345678901.123500
                                                    PRICE5=12345678901.123500
01-11 10:39:30.630 3680-3680/? D/PRICEINFO_GETSTR:  Processing Row 6
                                                    PRICE1=1.23457e+10
                                                    PRICE2=12345678901.123456
                                                    PRICE3=1.23457e+10
                                                    PRICE4=1.23457e+10
                                                    PRICE5=12345678901.123456
01-11 10:39:30.630 3680-3680/? D/PRICEINFO_GETDBL:  Processing Row 7
                                                    PRICE1=8888888888.880000
                                                    PRICE2=8888888888.880000
                                                    PRICE3=8888888888.880000
                                                    PRICE4=8888888888.880000
                                                    PRICE5=8888888888.880000
01-11 10:39:30.630 3680-3680/? D/PRICEINFO_GETSTR:  Processing Row 7
                                                    PRICE1=8.88889e+09
                                                    PRICE2=8888888888.88
                                                    PRICE3=8.88889e+09
                                                    PRICE4=8.88889e+09
                                                    PRICE5=8888888888.88
01-11 10:39:30.630 3680-3680/? D/PRICEINFO_GETDBL:  Processing Row 8
                                                    PRICE1=0.020000
                                                    PRICE2=0.020000
                                                    PRICE3=0.020000
                                                    PRICE4=0.020000
                                                    PRICE5=0.020000
01-11 10:39:30.634 3680-3680/? D/PRICEINFO_GETSTR:  Processing Row 8
                                                    PRICE1=0.02
                                                    PRICE2=0.02
                                                    PRICE3=0.02
                                                    PRICE4=0.02
                                                    PRICE5=0.02
01-11 10:39:30.634 3680-3680/? D/PRICEINFO_GETDBL:  Processing Row 9
                                                    PRICE1=56789.560000
                                                    PRICE2=56789.560000
                                                    PRICE3=56789.560000
                                                    PRICE4=56789.560000
                                                    PRICE5=56789.560000
01-11 10:39:30.634 3680-3680/? D/PRICEINFO_GETSTR:  Processing Row 9
                                                    PRICE1=56789.6
                                                    PRICE2=56789.56
                                                    PRICE3=56789.6
                                                    PRICE4=56789.6
                                                    PRICE5=56789.56
```

So :-

- For row 0 (999999999999999999999999999999999999999.99 stored via a double) using getDouble the column type is insignificant, but for getString there is a subtle difference when the column type is TEXT. However, precision loses the value (see caveat above).
- For row 1 (12345678901.123500 stored via a double) getDouble is fine for 15 significant figures. With getString all but the TEXT column lose out due to precision loss.
- For row 2 (9999999999.99 stored via a double) is very much the same findings as for row 1.
- For row 3 (0.01 stored via a double) is fine.
- For row 4 (45678.45 stored via double) precision loss is an issue for getString except when it is a TEXT column.
- For rows 5-9 the data is stored via a string, TEXT and BLOB columns accurately store the value in all cases with no precision loss. Otherwise the results are similar.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. This Helps me; but how i can get this real entered prices without DecimalFormat?

Comment: @BhoomikaPatel, I suggest that you update the question to show the code that you are having an issue with. If you don;t want `9999999999.990000` but want `9999999999.99` then simply change `final DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#0.000000");` to `final DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#0.00");` and use that format. The longer format was used primarily to show more examples of lost precision.

Comment: Thanks For this. I am got my result with format: DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##"); This will not returns additional 0's if i didn't enter them.