# Formatting Double to String?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

String.format("%,.0f", 200000000000000000000000.0)

-> 199,999,999,999,999,980,000,000
why?

Comment: Because of the precision of the internal representation. See [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken?r=SearchResults)

Comment: @LongNguyenVan you may look here for solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48201462/store-big-price-value-in-database-along-with-decimal-point-in-sqlite-database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem has been solved

String.format("%,.0f", BigDecimal( 200000000000000000000000.0, MathContext.DECIMAL64))

Answer (score 0):

Understand the Double Data type - it is an approximation of amount and scale.

The Following assignment:

```
double d = 2.00000000000f;
```

will generate a value of 1.9999999 at times when printed.  What you are seeing here is magnification of that.  Double Data types also have a maximum (implementation-dependant) of how many places of significance they can support (upto 15 generally) - which is why the last 6 digits are all zeros (0)

For your particular solution, if you don't require Floating-point Data, stick to Integer.

Comment: but when i tried it, it was scaled with 21 zeros(0)

Answer (score 0):

It is because current processors(and most VMs) work like that if use default data types. [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-off_error) it is explained in details

If you want precision use [`BigDecimal`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html). This class is specifically intended for situations like this - to be used in currency related stuff and scientific calculations.

To format decimals in proper way Java has [`DecimalFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html)

```
String pattern = "###,###.###";
DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat(pattern);

String format = decimalFormat.format(123456789.123);
System.out.println(format); // -> 123.456.789,123
```

[Here](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-internationalization/decimalformat.html) is nice tutorial about it

Hope it helps.

Comment: still be with value  200000000000000000000000.0

Comment: @LongNguyenVan with DecimalFormat - yes because if uses the same double as you - I showed it just to show how to format decimals correct in java. Use BigDecimal for giant numbers - you have control over rounding using this class.

Comment: thanks Use BigDecimal and MathContext

Comment: @Long Nguyen Van please accept answer if it is correct